# Azure Bot AAD App requirement and general security related questions

Tags: azure, botframework

I've got a working bot based on Azure Bot framework.

- "Azure Bot" resource deployed to Azure
- Bot code (.NET7) deployed to a web app in Azure
- Channel configuration for Teams completed

I struggle to understand the following things:

1. What is the Azure AD App ID exactly required for?
2. Why is the AAD app ID's secret required in the .NET app? I can see that the app's endpoint `/api/messages` is called by the Bot Service, so *that* would need the secret...?
3. When I use my bot from within Teams, another "app" is created. The Teams "app" is nothing but a manifest JSON. It seems I can share this manifest/app package with anybody and they would be able to upload it into Teams and use my bot? How is the bot being protected by being accessed from random users?